# Remove duplicates data from a dataset based on 2 column values

Tags: c#, duplicates, dataset, compare

Here is my code. I just want to compare two data sets columns and exclude same records. I tried this 
code. It exclude the same records but it also generated duplicate data.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < ds2. Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            { 
                for each (Data Row dr2 in ds1. Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    string table2 = dr2["code"].ToString();
                    if (i.ToString() != table2.ToString())
                    {
                        dsnew. Tables[0].Rows.Add(i);                     


                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: is this c# code?

Comment: yes its c# code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strange comparison. you don't seem to be using the records in ds2. only the count of ds2.

i think you are getting duplicates because you are

- comparing each element in ds2 with 1 element in ds1 before deciding to place it in dsnew

try

- comparing each element in ds2 with all elements in ds1 before deciding to place it in dsnew

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
  {
      bool found = false;
      foreach (DataRow dr2 in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
      {
          string table2 = dr2["code"].ToString();
          if (i.ToString() == table2.ToString())
          {
              found = true;
          }
      }

      if(!found) dsnew.Tables[0].Rows.Add(i);
  }
  ```